# Spring REST - /account/{id} - access only for user who exists in database

Tags: database, spring, rest, authentication

I am developing an application in which I have controllers mapped to `/account/{id}/...` and my aim is to let some client use these urls only for user whose "id" exists in database.

**Process looks like this:**

1) client creates new account (new user is added to database with auto-generated id)

2) client logs in

3) client can access for example: `/account/{id}/something`

**For now I have my controller mapped like this:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/{id}")
public class ControllerName {
```

But in every controller's method I am checking if user who is calling my service exists in db(by checking if ID exists).
I suppose that it is not good(problematic), because of same-code repeating multiple times.

Is there any way to avoid repeating myself and automize it? Or is this good approach to check if user exists in service call?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can write Interceptor or filter for it,like below.

```
  <mvc:interceptors>
     <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/controller1/path1"/>
        <mvc:mapping path="/controller2/path2"/>
        //other controller path
        <bean class="com.test.interceptor.UserInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptor>
   </mvc:interceptors>
```

Then in side this interceptor you can verify user existence.

```
public class UserInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    //Inside prehandle() method you can verify user existence
}
```

Similarly if you want,you can use filter.

Comment: I thought about it as well, but I wonder if it is good idea. I did it 5 minutes ago but deleted because I thought it is to wordy.